# ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host httpbin.org:80 ssl:False [getaddrinfo failed]

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I try to make an asynchronous request to fetch a URL (Anaconda Python 3.6.3 64-bit on Windows 7)

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def hello(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            response = await response.read()
            print(response)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(hello("http://httpbin.org/headers"))
```

(code from [this article](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html))

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-89-ff1fbb8cc713>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/me/Code/async_fetch.py', wdir='C:/Users/me/Code/')

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/me/Code/async_fetch.py", line 19, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(hello("http://httpbin.org/headers"))

  File "C:\APP\Anaconda3\envs\dashboards\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 467, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()

  File "C:/Users/me/Code/async_fetch.py", line 13, in hello
    async with session.get(url) as response:

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 783, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 320, in _request
    traces=traces

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 418, in connect
    traces=traces

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 733, in _create_connection
    traces=traces

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 823, in _create_direct_connection
    raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc

ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host httpbin.org:80 ssl:False [getaddrinfo failed]
```

Comment: Can you open `http://httpbin.org/headers` on same machine from browser?

Comment: Yes. And a regular `requests.get("http://httpbin.org/headers")` works just fine.

Comment: Everything works fine on my laptop.

Comment: Does your network require the use of a proxy server? Minor differences in reading the proxy configuration could explain why `requests` works, but `aiohttp` doesn't, all on the same computer.